# How on earth can I VIEW RASTER ATTRIBUTE TABLE IN QGIS?

Tags: qgis

How on earth can I VIEW RASTER ATTRIBUTE TABLE IN QGIS?
In arcgis it is easy to view raster attribute. QGIS has no function to do same and this leaves me frustrated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is not an appropriate question for this site. You could try gis.stackexchange.com instead

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin called [RasterAttributeTable](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/RasterAttributeTable/), with this plugin you can open the attribute table of a raster layer just like a vector layer.